# Is there any way to render the WordPress Gutenberg core/embed block in PHP by passing in the URL?

Tags: block-editor, oembed

I'm trying to render the block HTML dynamically by injecting it within a core/query block. The injection is working fine using `DOMDocument`, but I can't find out how to render the embed HTML. I can use `wp_oembed_get` for the iframe, but I need the wrapper DIVs, aspect ratio by provider, and so on.

Comment: As far as I know, no. The aspect ratio class is calculated/selected in JavaScript in the editor, and there's no equivalent in PHP. You can see the function responsible here: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/a1a14685dba6c082ecb9c799842fe05be1c169ec/packages/block-library/src/embed/util.js#L187